# Why does my local branch show (local out of date) despite doing git fetch?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

My team mate updated his branch `feature1` on remote while I was working on `feature2`.

Now when I do `$ git remote show origin`, it shows -

`Local refs configured for 'git push':`

`feature1 pushes to feature1 (local out of date)`

I am currently checked out on branch `feature2`, and I tried all the commands below, but the state of `feature1` doesn't change to `(up to date)`. (All commands execute without any errors)

`$ git fetch origin`

`$ git fetch --all`

`$ git fetch origin feature2`

Why does this happen? What am I missing?

Comment: You'd have to pull. Fecthing is just half the way : it fetches new refs but does not update any local branch.

Answer (score 1):

[git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) just download objects and refs from another repository. To get the changes into your branch you have to do a [git merge](http://oin%20two%20or%20more%20development%20histories%20together).

To do both things in one step you can use [git pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

In your case:

```
git merge origin/feature2
```

Answer (score 1):

After using `git fetch` to obtain new commits from some other Git, you must choose how to combine those new commits with any of your own existing commits.

There are two main ways to combine commits:

- `git merge`
- `git rebase`

These are very different actions in some cases.  In other cases—including specifically the case where *all* of your existing commits just came from that other Git in the first place, and you never make any of your own commits, and the person managing the other Git behaves well—they do exactly the same thing so that it won't matter which one you do (unless the second command fails; see below).

My own process is generally: run `git fetch`, inspect what happened, then choose which of `git merge` or `git rebase` I want to do, if I want to do any of them yet.  Then, I do the second command that I'd like to do based on the results of this inspection, or I hold off entirely based on the results of this inspection.

If you are sure about which second command you'd like to use, you can use `git pull`, which runs `git fetch`, then runs one of these other two Git commands.  You choose in advance, before seeing what `git fetch` brings, *which* other Git command to run.  The default second command is `git merge`, so if you're absolutely sure, in advance, that you want to `git fetch` and then `git merge`, you can run `git pull`.  If you're absolutely sure, in advance, that you want to run `git rebase` second, you can run `git pull --rebase`.

Note that both `git merge` and `git rebase` can *fail*, and leave you with a mess to clean up.  If you run `git pull` and its second command fails, you're still in the middle of whichever second command you chose to have `git pull` run.  You'll still need to clean up the mess.  You can wait until this actually happens to learn *how* to clean it up, but remember that the *way* to clean it up depends on *which* second command you chose!  I like to avoid `git pull` so that I know which second command I used via the fact that *I* typed it in. :-)

Comment: _My own process is generally: run git fetch, inspect what happened_

How exactly do you inspect the fetch result after running the fetch command? I mean, which command do you use?

Comment: Mostly `git log`, on the remote-tracking name(s) I care about (e.g., `origin/master`). You can also read the output of `git fetch` but it's not very friendly. A `git log master..origin/master` tells me what's now available on `origin/master` that I could rebase or merge with.